# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "version" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jruby

I changed my project from ruby rails to jruby rails. When I execute `jruby -S rake db:setup` I get this error:

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0212s
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "version" does not exist
```

I was looking for solution in google but i didn't find anything. I must point out that before jruby everything was ok. I could make migrations etc.

Answer (score 2):

ok I found solution. The problem was in schema_migrations. There wasn't column 'version'.

In rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP TABLE schema_migrations")
```

next

```
rake db:setup
```